# Open a file case-insensitively in Ruby under Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, case-insensitive

Is there a way to open a file case-insensitively in Ruby under Linux? For example, given the string `foo.txt`, can I open the file `FOO.txt`?

One possible way would be reading all the filenames in the directory and manually search the list for the required file, but I'm looking for a more direct method.

Comment: What if multiple files match? Pick one of them at random?

Comment: @Ignacio: Yes, that is the only reasonable option. But that case is unlikely in my situation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One approach would be to write a little method to build a case insensitive glob for a given filename:

```
def ci_glob(filename)
  glob = ''
  filename.each_char do |c|
    glob += c.downcase != c.upcase ? "[#{c.downcase}#{c.upcase}]" : c
  end
  glob
end

irb(main):024:0> ci_glob('foo.txt')
=> "[fF][oO][oO].[tT][xX][tT]"
```

and then you can do:

```
filename = Dir.glob(ci_glob('foo.txt')).first
```

Alternatively, you can write the directory search you suggested quite concisely. e.g.

```
filename = Dir.glob('*').find { |f| f.downcase == 'foo.txt' }
```

---

Prior to Ruby 3.1 it was possible to use the `FNM_CASEFOLD` option to make `glob` case insensitive e.g.

```
filename = Dir.glob('foo.txt', File::FNM_CASEFOLD).first
if filename
  # use filename here
else
  # no matching file
end
```

The documentation [suggested `FNM_CASEFOLD` couldn't be used with glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) but it *did* actually work in older Ruby versions. However, as mentioned by [lildude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573122/lildude) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651952/open-a-file-case-insensitively-in-ruby-under-linux/3652293?noredirect=1#comment131378420_3652293), the [behaviour has now been brought inline](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4583) with the documentation and so this approach shouldn't be used.

Comment: For most of the `IO` and `File` methods, Ruby simply passes everything through to libc. So, I guess this might basically randomly work or not, depending on how your operating system's libc works.

Comment: @Jörg Thanks. I have updated the answer with a couple of other ideas that avoid the need to rely on `FNM_CASEFOLD`.

Comment: On my system, FNM_CASEFOLD is honoured in Ruby 2.0.0 but ignored in Ruby 2.2.0. Definitely not reliable.

Comment: `FNM_CASEFOLD` is no longer honoured on 3.1 as of https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4583 which brings the `Dir.glob` behaviour inline with what the docs have been saying for years https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/File/File/Constants.html#FNM_CASEFOLD

Comment: Thanks @lildude - I've updated the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dir.glob with the `FNM_CASEFOLD` flag to get a list of all filenames that match the given name except for case. You can then just use `first` on the resulting array to get any result back or use `min_by` to get the one that matches the case of the orignial most closely.

```
def find_file(f)
  Dir.glob(f, File::FNM_CASEFOLD).min_by do |f2|
    f.chars.zip(f2.chars).count {|c1,c2| c1 != c2}
  end
end

system "touch foo.bar"
system "touch Foo.Bar"
Dir.glob("FOO.BAR", File::FNM_CASEFOLD) #=> ["foo.bar", "Foo.Bar"]
find_file("FOO.BAR") #=> ["Foo.Bar"]
```