# In Ruby, how can I interpret (expand) a glob relative to a directory?

Tags: ruby, glob

## Wider context: Case-insensitive filename on case sensitive file system

Given the path of a directory (as a string, might be relative to the current working dir or absolute), I'd like to open a specific file. I know the file's filename except for the its case. (It could be `TASKDATA.XML`, `TaskData.xml` or even `tAsKdAtA.xMl`.)

Inspired by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652293/674064) to [Open a file case-insensitively in Ruby under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651952/open-a-file-case-insensitively-in-ruby-under-linux), I've come up with this little module to produce a glob for matching the file's name:

```
module Utils
  def self.case_insensitive_glob_string(string)
    string.each_char.map do |c|
      cased = c.upcase != c.downcase
      cased ? "[#{c.upcase}#{c.downcase}]" : c
    end.join
  end
end
```

For my specific case, I'd call this with

```
 Utils.case_insensitive_glob_string('taskdata.xml')
```

and would get

```
'[Tt][Aa][Ss][Kk][Dd][Aa][Tt][Aa].[Xx][Mm][Ll]'
```

## Specific context: glob relative to a dir ≠ pwd

Now I have to expand the glob, i.e. match it against actual files in the given directory. Unfortunately, [`Dir.glob(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) doesn't seem have an argument to pass a directory('s path) relative to which the glob should be expanded. Intuitively, it would make sense to me to create a `Dir` object and have that handle the glob:

```
d = Dir.new(directory_path)
# => #<Dir:/the/directory>

filename = d.glob(Utils.case_insensitive_glob_string('taskdata.xml')).first() # I wish ...
# NoMethodError: undefined method `glob' for #<Dir:/the/directory>
```

... but `glob` only exists as a class method, not as an instance method. (Anybody know why that's true of so many of `Dir`'s methods that would perfectly make sense *relative* to a *specific* directory?)

So it looks like I have two options:

1. Change the current working dir to the given directory

   or
2. expand the filename's glob in combination with the directory path

The first option is easy: Use [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Dir.html#method-c-chdir). But because this is in a Gem, and I don't want to mess with the environment of the users of my Gem, I shy away from it. (It's probably somewhat better when used with the block synopsis than manually (or not) resetting the working dir when I'm done.)

The second option *looks* easy. Simply do

```
taskdata_xml_name_glob = Utils.case_insensitive_glob_string('taskdata.xml')
taskdata_xml_path_glob = File.join(directory_path, taskdata_xml_name_glob)
filename = Dir.glob(taskdata_xml_path_glob).first()
```

, right? Almost. When `directory_path` contains characters that have a special meaning in globs, they will **wrongly be expanded**, when I only want glob expansion on the filename. This is unlikely, but as the path is provided by the Gem user, I have to account for it, anyway.

## Question

Should I escape `directory_path` before `File.join`ing it with the filename glob? If so, is there a facility to do that or would I have to code the escaping function myself?

Or should I use a different approach (be it `chdir`, or something yet different)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were implementing that behaviour, I would go with filtering an array, returned by [`Dir#entries`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Dir.html#method-c-entries):

```
Dir.entries("#{target}").select { |f| f =~ /\A#{filename}\z/i }
```

Please be aware that on unix platform both `.` and `..` entries *will be listed as well*, but they are unlikely to be matched on the second step. Also, probably the filename should be escaped with [`Regexp.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
Dir.entries("#{target}").select { |f| f =~ /\A#{Regexp.escape(filename)}\z/i }
```

Comment: Good idea. While I'm somewhat familiar with regexps, I didn't consider them here, as 'filename matching' just screamed 'globs' to me, but your approach is much more elegant than all the hoop-jumping I'd do with globs. As a bonus, this probably works with Dir-like objects, like [rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip)'s directory streams, too.